# Create.cshtml on the index.cshtml page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have renderad a CRUD with .net and have the following files in the same folder.

Create.cshtml, Delete.cshtml, Details.cshtml, Edit.cshtml, Index.cshtml

Now it is a link to create a new record on the index page

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

But I want the create form to be on the index page.

I tested to use PartialView (I do not know whether it is better to copy the code from create.cshtml in index.cshtml or to use two files but I get the same error).

Changed the `return` in the controller to `return PartialView(board);`

And the view to `@Html.Partial("Create")`

But I get the compiling error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Klotterplank.Models.Board]', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Klotterplank.Models.Board'.

This is the model I use in index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Klotterplank.Models.Board>
```

And this is the model I use in create.cshtml

```
@model Klotterplank.Models.Board
```

Comment: You need a view model with properties for each property of `Board` that your editing, plus a collection property for the existing `Board` - refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: Maybe you can try to use this partial [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.partial(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object%29) and pass the `Board` instance accordingly.

Comment: The problem with using a partial is that it will cause problems if you submit and you need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid

Answer (score 0):

If you use a PartialView in a parent page with a different Model, you have to pass a different model to the Html Helper like this:

```
@Html.Partial("Create", new Klotterplank.Models.Board())
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells pretty much itself: [When a partial view is instantiated, it gets a copy of the parent view’s ViewData dictionary](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/partial.html#accessing-data-from-partial-views). Your `Create` view needs data of different type, so you can provide it like this:

```
@Html.Partial("Create", viewModel)
```

`viewModel` can be equal to `Model.Fist()` (since on your `Index` view you have a collection of boards as model) for example.